# Segmentation fault, parsing, C

Tags: c, parsing, csv

I am writing a c file that takes in information from a .csv file, parse it, then delete whatever ive parsed. The problem that i am having is that, after it runs through one line of the .csv file i get a segmentation fault. I heard i can use GDB to help with this, but I don't know how to use that. This is my .c file

```
void parser(int argc, char ** argv)
{
FILE * songList;
char * theString;
char * theToken;
char songs[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];
char artist[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];
char title[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];
int x;
int length;
double size;
char * type;
char songType[1];
char songTypeC;
MusicRec * next;

theToken = "";


songList = fopen(argv[1], "r");

if(songList == NULL)/*returns an error if file wasnt opened*/
{
    printf("error opening file\n");
}

else
{
    while(fgets(songs, ROOM_STRING_LENGTH, songList) != NULL)/*gets one string at a time until fgets equals NULL*/
    {
        theString = malloc((sizeof(char)*(strlen(songs)+1))); /* mallocs some memory*/
        strcpy(theString, songs);
        x = 0;
        for(theToken = strtok(theString, ","); theToken; theToken = strtok(NULL, ","))
        {
            switch(x)
            {
                case 0:
                strcpy(artist, theToken);
                printf("%s\n", artist);
                break;

                case 1:
                strcpy(title, theToken);
                printf("%s\n", title);
                break;

                case 2:
                sscanf(theToken, "%d",&length); 
                printf("%d\n", length);
                break;

                case 3:
                size = atof(theToken);
                printf("%.2f\n", size);
                break;

                case 4: 
                type = malloc(sizeof(char));
                sscanf(theToken, "%s",type);
                songType[0] = *type;
                songTypeC = songType[0];
                printf("%c\n", songTypeC);
                free(type);
                break;
            }
            x++;

        }
        next = malloc(sizeof(MusicRec));
        next = createRecord(title, artist, size, length, songTypeC);
        /*print = printRecord(toPrint);*/
        destroyRecord(next);  
        /*free(print);*/
        free(next);
    }

free(theString);
free(theToken);
fclose(songList);

}
}
```

These are the 2 functions being called:

```
char * printRecord(MusicRec * toPrint)
{
char token[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];
char * pointer;

sprintf(token, "%s (%s):%d[%.2f]", toPrint->title, toPrint->artist, toPrint->lengthInSeconds, toPrint->sizeInKB);
pointer = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(token));
strcpy(pointer, token);
return(pointer);
}


void destroyRecord(MusicRec * theRecord)
{
free(theRecord->title);
free(theRecord->artist);
}
```

Comment: You might want to read the [GDB user manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). In short, build your program with debug information (`-g` flag to GCC), and start `gdb` with your program. In GDB `run` your program, possibly with arguments. GDB will stop when the crash happens, and let you examine the function call stack with the `bt` command, and walk up the call stack with the `up` command. If GDB doesn't stop in your code, go `up` the stack until you are in your code. The you can `print` values of variables.

Comment: At least you should run your program in the debugger, and edit your question to include the call stack (the output of the `bt` command when it crashes).

Comment: By the way, you have to remember that strings in C are actually one character more than reported by `strlen`, the terminating `'\0'` character. You miss this in a couple of places.

Comment: `type = malloc(sizeof(char));
                sscanf(theToken, "%s",type);` : too small. `pointer = malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(token));
strcpy(pointer, token);` : too small. `next = malloc(sizeof(MusicRec));
        next = createRecord(title, artist, size, length, songTypeC);
        ...
        free(next);` : `next` modified.

Comment: Can you provide the first 2 or 3 records in your csv file? This would be a big help.

Comment: This is an example of 1 lines: 
The Kills,Wild Charms,75,2457.6,a

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this piece of code:

```
case 4: 
  type = malloc(sizeof(char));
  sscanf(theToken, "%s",type);
```

You're allocating a 1 byte string and reading an arbitrary length string into it.
That is prone to a segfault if the input token is larger than 1.

Comment: I changed the (sizeof(char)) to be (sizeof(char)*MAX_LENGTH), and i am still seg faulting